# Optional but not empty field in WTForms

Tags: python, validation, wtforms

The Optional validator allows for both empty values and if the value is not present (from the [docs](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validators.html#wtforms.validators.Optional)):

> class wtforms.validators.Optional(strip_whitespace=True)
>
> Allows empty input and stops the validation chain from continuing.
>
> If input is empty, also removes prior errors (such as processing
>   errors) from the field.

I have some additional validators on a field, and I would like if those validators ran even if the input is an empty string. The builtin `Optional` validator makes the rest of the validators skipped if the input was an empty string. Is there a built in or any other way to achieve this?

#### Edit: More specifics about my usecase

I am using this form to validate `PUT` requests. Let's say I have User entities with `username`s as ID and `middlename`s as an optional field. Then the validator for the fields would look something like:

```
class UserUpdateForm(Form):
    username = fields.StringField('username', [
        validators.Optional(),
        validators.Length(min=5, max=500)
    ])
    middlename = fields.StringField('middlename', [
        validators.Optional()
    ])
```

So I would allow for `PUT` requests that does not have a `username` or `middlename` parameter, and those would leave the fields untouched. However, when the parameter is present and is an empty string, I would like the `username` field validation fail because of the `Length` validator, but I would allow the `middlename` field to be set to the empty string.

From another perspective: I would like to distinguish non-present parameters and empty string parameters.

Comment: Can't you just remove the Optional validator? So the other validators will get executed and you are still free to provide empty values.

Comment: @MrLeeh Good idea, but I cannot. I updated the question with my reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took a look at the source of the `Optional` validator:

```
class Optional(object):
    ...
    def __call__(self, form, field):
        if not field.raw_data or isinstance(field.raw_data[0], string_types) and not self.string_check(field.raw_data[0]):
            field.errors[:] = []
            raise StopValidation()
```

As you can see in `and not self.string_check(field.raw_data[0])`, empty strings are explicitly considered here. I wonder what would happen if I sent two values like `a=foo&a=&b=bar`.

Anyway, the quick solution for me was to implement a new validator:

```
class OptionalButNotEmpty(object):
    """
    Allows missing but not empty input and stops the validation chain from continuing.
    """
    # Code is a modified version of `Optional` (https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/wtforms/validators.py#L148)
    field_flags = ('optional', )

    def __call__(self, form, field):
        if not field.raw_data:
            raise wtforms.validators.StopValidation()
```